# MySQL server global error log

Tags: mysql, sql, logging

I need to capture all of the query errors that are happening on my MySQL server.  I've looked into the general_log and that appears to just save the queries, but NOT the result (whether there was an error thrown or not).  I've heard some people say the server can't do this, and it can only be done on the client.  This seems like a common function, so I would be surprised if there was no option to log query errors on the server.

How can I log these query errors?

Comment: One could insert a [MySQL Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-proxy.html) and set the [`log-level`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-proxy-configuration.html#option_mysql-proxy_log-level) option as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error.log in MySQL like you desire, see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-logs.html) what you can log with MySQL.
The only way is to look in your own error.logs e.g. in php:

- catch the [mysql_error](https://www.php.net/function.mysql-error) or [mysqli_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) in php and write your own log-file

or

- look in your apache-error-log when you didn´t catch your errors